# how to use libc++ and libstdc++ for different libraries in one project

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

enter link description herecurrently I am working on embedding unity in iOS project and I am almost completing it. However, I am having issues with my libraries.

I am embedding unity+Vuforia in my iOS project, which means in build setting c++ standard library, I have to use libc++ to get Vuforia and unity working.

On the other hand, I have some old libraries(libFMDB.a; lingos.a; libproj4.a; libShapekit.a; libSpatialDBKit.a; libspatialite.a; libsqlite3.a)  that should use libstdc++ in setting. If I simply set libc++ for my build setting, I will get errors.
[ErrorScreenShotImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbAYz.png)

What should I do at this point to get everything complied?

Thank you!!!!

Comment: why can't you just use `libc++`? Its not clear what the problem is.

Comment: additionally, you should be aware that the latest SDKs don't even provide libstdc++ so you wont be able to run on modern systems with what you want to do.

Comment: @BradAllred I am sorry for my unclear description. I cannot use libc++, because lingos.a and some other libraries have to use libstdc++. If I set c++ standard library to libc++, it will have complie error:   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::string::operator+=(char const*)", referenced from:
      geos::algorithm::LineIntersector::toString() const in libgeos.a(LineIntersector.o)
      geos::geomgraph::DirectedEdgeStar::print() in libgeos.a(DirectedEdgeStar-8A1632E441A524A8.o)
      geos::operation::relate::EdgeEndBundle::print() in libgeos.a(EdgeEndBundle.o)

Comment: recompile those libraries with `libc++`! this has nothing to do with `libc++` vs `libstdc++` they are both equivalent (from an API perspective) conforming implementations of the c++ standard library.

Comment: BTW `libsqlite3` is part of the ios SDK so you can just use the provided one rather than your own.

Comment: @BradAllred hmmm.. I'm pretty new in iOS. Could you maybe take sometime to explain how to recompile those libraries with libc++ in details? I am so sorry to ask stupid questions...

Comment: just open a new question about it and somebody will tell you. mostly you should be able to download new versions from github that are already compiled with libc++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not do this!**

Why?

1. depending on the name mangling scheme used it might not even be possible because `libc++` is going to have the same symbols as `libstdc++`
2. if there are no symbol collisions you are probably going to run into undefined behavior when you take objects from one library and mix them with objects/functions from the other.
3. `class` structures will not be compatible. Internal class structures will be implemented or laid out differently.
4. `libstdc++` is no longer available on iOS 12. Your program will not run on it.
5. The correct way to fix your problem is to download/compile updated versions of your libraries. Period.